# $scope Is not accessable inside PageMethods.GetEmployeeDetails

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, webforms, angularjs-scope

$scope is not being accessed inside PageMethods.GetEmployeeDetails Can any one guide me thanks.

```
function FirstController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.source = 10;

    PageMethods.GetEmployeeDetails(function Success(data) {
        $scope.source = 11;
        $scope.MyData = data;

    });
}
```

Comment: I want to get "data" and use it in UI, so i need to assign it to $scope veriable??

Comment: I think your controller defination is wrong. Is this the full controller? if not, please add the full controller defination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe based upon the question that you want to be able to call `GetEmployeeDetails` from your UI/DOM

In order to do that you will need to define that question on your `$scope`:

```
$scope.GetEmployeeDetails(function Success(data) {...
```

then in your markup (which will need to be within the scope of your controller:

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
    <button type="button" ng-click="GetEmployeeDetails(data)">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

### Edit based upon OP's comments below

*The issue the above fixes is to allow a method to be accessible via scope and therefore DOM*

**This is how to allow a call outside of "angular-land" (aka not in an angular module) to recognize changes to scope**

Since the method `PageMethods.GetEmployeeDetails` is not recognized/managed by angular it has no idea the `$scope` may have changed upon callback. So in order to handle that scenario you must tell angular to reevaluate the `$scope` to allow angular to refresh the DOM as shown here:

```
PageMethods.GetEmployeeDetails(function Success(data) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.source = 11;
        $scope.MyData = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm Getting json data from PageMethods, how can i replace it with $scope

Comment: @AmaanKhan I've updated my answer based upon your clarification, but left the original in case you or others find that useful.